# WiFi Problem Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, atheros

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04, when I did I installed it with wifi internet connection to download the extra packages. That was being in my house but at 7 minutes I disconnected or the connection is unstable, I'm still connected but it will not let me open any page, the only option I have found is to reboot the system to let me connect again because Wireless network and reconnecting leaves me.

I have an ASUS TP300LD with the next specs:

RAM: 8 GiB

Processor:  Intel® Core™ i3 4010U Processor

Graphic: NVIDIA Geforce 820M

SO: 64 bits

```
$ uname -r
3.16.0-031600-generic

$ lspci | grep Wireless
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

$ ifconfig

lo        Link encap:Bucle local  
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:11509 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:11509 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:1611878 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:1611878 (1.6 MB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 40:e2:30:fa:da:87  
          Direc. inet:192.168.0.3  Difus.:192.168.0.15  Másc:255.255.255.240
          Dirección inet6: fe80::b0b2:1166:51f:e58b/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:1686916 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:1078594 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:2378467565 (2.3 GB)  TX bytes:121150140 (121.1 MB)
```

I hope you can help me solve my problem
Tell me what information you need so that you can help me better.

Btw, thxs.

Comment: Change the wireless encryption settings, at the router, to WPA2-AES. Troubleshoot from there.

Comment: @MichaelBay, can i use WPA2-PSK-AES?

Comment: It's the same thing. What matters is not using any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and especially not TKIP.

Comment: Why are you using that antique kernel in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I only install Ubuntu, Im using it out of the box